# How to get the value of an option in a dropdown by knowing only the id of select tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

here is my js code:

```
 var currentsecondarycategory = document.getElementById("se_category");
if(currentsecondarycategory.childElementCount > 1)
{
    if(!currentsecondarycategory.value.match(whiteSpaceRegExp))
    {
        error = 1;
        alert("please enter a secondary category for the Item.");
        currentElement.select();
        currentElement.focus();
        return;
    }
}
```

i want to check if their is only one option,then how to check the value of that option,so that if it is other than the value "No records found",then i can apply the 2nd if condition above to that option also.please help me.
 here the options are coming dynamically,so not possible to check by a single id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.value` property of `currentsecondarycategory`. Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the process:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nNy3/

HTML

```
<select id="dropdown"><option value="test">that's the value</option></select>
```

JS

```
console.log(document.getElementById("dropdown").value);
```

If you want to get the text of the `option` tag then use:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").options[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `currentsecondarycategory.childNodes` to get the `<option>` nodes within the `<select>`. If there is only one option, it will be `currentsecondarycategory.childNodes[0]`, and its value will be `currentsecondarycategory.childNodes[0].value`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentsecondarycategory = document.getElementById("se_category");
if(currentsecondarycategory.selectedIndex == 0){
    alert('put your message here');
    return false;
}
```

**currentsecondarycategory.selectedIndex** it will return the selected index of the selectbox

please try this...may helpful